# Using cfc with threads in a coldfusion page

Tags: multithreading, coldfusion, cfc

I have a component "bulletin.cfc" which contains lots of functions.

My main page has two threads running on it using the cfthread tag.

Coming from .net I thought I would create two instrances of the component, and use one in each thread. This way they wouldnt mess with each other and I wouldnt need to worry about putting locks in the functions.

```
<cfset bullObj = new bulletin()>
<cfset bullObj2 = new bulletin()>
```

Is this correct?

EDIT:

Thanks for the answers so far, I still can't understand a problem that is happening with this though. I have the following code inside two seperate cfthread elements:

```
<cfset listCount = 1>
    <cftry>
    <cfquery name="ins" datasource="#datasourceVar#" >
        INSERT INTO element_user_shown
        (elementid, userid, date_shown)
        (
        <cfloop list="#elementIDList#" index="lcv">
        SELECT #lcv#, #tmpuserid#, GETDATE()
            <cfif listCount LT listlen(elementIDList)>
                UNION ALL
            </cfif>
        <cfset listCount = listCount + 1>
        </cfloop>   
        )               
    </cfquery>
```

This runs about 70,000 times a night but gets about 3-4 errors each time. Checking the sql that errors it looks like

```
        INSERT INTO element_user_shown
                        (elementid, userid, date_shown)
                        (

                            SELECT 621, 267509, GETDATE()

                            UNION ALL

                            SELECT 586, 267509, GETDATE()

                            UNION ALL

                            SELECT 594, 267509, GETDATE()

                            UNION ALL

                            SELECT 613, 267509, GETDATE()

                            SELECT 622, 267509, GETDATE()

                            SELECT 599, 267509, GETDATE()

                            SELECT 602, 267509, GETDATE()                               

                        )
```

Comment: does your `Bulletin.cfc` have state?  If it doesn't, and all vars in functions are var-scoped correctly, you do not need another instance of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that your instances are passed by reference so the *potential* might be there to have a concurrency problem. But if your function arguments are properly paramed and you are not changing properties as a part of the instance (in other words this is an interface and not a bean) you can safely reuse the same instance. Each function call is it's own scope and variables within and returned are for the life of the function call.

Comment: All the variables in functions are local scoped. I was concerned that two threads going into the same function at the same time would be altering the same "local" variable though, if there was only one instance of the component

Comment: As Henry said - if you are using it the way you described you are ok with the singleton interface approach.